# Failed to resolve module specifier "module". when importing @microsoft/signalr into nx app created in angular

Tags: angular, signalr, nrwl-nx, asp.net-core-signalr

When I am using @microsoft/signalr in my angular monorepo with nx, I am getting below error -

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "module". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

Uncaught ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk vendors-node_modules_microsoft_signalr_dist_esm_index_js failed.
(missing: http://localhost:4202/vendors-node_modules_microsoft_signalr_dist_esm_index_js.js)
at webpack_require.f.j (jsonp chunk loading:27:1)
at ensure chunk:6:1
at Array.reduce ()
at webpack_require.e (ensure chunk:5:1)
at Object.get (sharing:40:1)
at get (consumes:80:1)
at getStrictSingletonVersion (consumes:50:1)
at consumes:133:1
at consumes:85:1
at webpack/sharing/consume/default/@microsoft/signalr/@microsoft/signalr (consumes:139:1)
```

If I run in with `--configuration=production` flag, it works fine.

Comment: I also am facing similar issue after upgrading our app to angular 16, we use module-federation and @microsoft/signalr. Same error, but the app works if we run it in production mode. We don't use `nx` for our app, just a multi project app made with angular-architects.

Comment: Yes, it seems some issue with web module.